# Center alignment in dropdown

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I need to center icons in dropdown. When I have text in dropdown item instead of icon, it is in center, but icon not:

[image]

Here is my code:

```
    <div class="btn-group pull-right">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-link dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
        Click
      </button>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right" role="menu">
        <li>
          <a href="" class="text-center">A</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="" class="text-center"><i class="fa fa-th-large"></i></a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href=""><i class="fa fa-th"></i></a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
```

How to center icons in dropdown?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to override Bootstrap predefined values using `!important`. Below is the working snippet

```css
li {
  display: inline;
  background: red;
  position: relative;
  padding: 5px 20px!important;
  margin: 1px;
}

.dropdown-menu>li>a {
  display: inline!important;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  padding: 0px !important;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.8.1/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-50oBUHEmvpQ+1lW4y57PTFmhCaXp0ML5d60M1M7uH2+nqUivzIebhndOJK28anvf" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

  <div class="btn-group pull-right">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-link dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
        Click
      </button>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right text-center" role="menu">
      <li class="text-center">
        <a href="" class="text-center">A</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="" class="text-center"><i class="fa fa-th-large"></i></a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="" class="text-center"><i class="fa fa-th"></i></a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```